# need help to convert htaccess rule to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, php

Could anyone please help me to convert following .htaccess rule to nginx.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .jpg -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this, works for most rules: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

```
# nginx configuration 
location / 
{ 
   if (!-e $request_filename)
   { 
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.jpg; 
   } 
}
```